# How to combine python strings and ints?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have been working on a small toolkit for awhile  now as a way to learn basic python.  part of this toolkit is the code that follows this explanation. It is a basic network enumeration script, to simply ping all ip addresses in your local subnet. However I am having an issue implementing a few pieces.
first the code

```
ip1=raw_input()

if ip1 == None:
    ip="192.168.0.x"
else:
    ip=ip1

ipend="1"

while ipend != 255:
    ip.replace("x", ipend) 

    attempt=subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if ("unreachable" in attempt):
        pass
    else:
        print "The host at ", ip, "is UP!"

    ipend += 1

if ipend == "255":
    subprocess.stop
        raw_input("Thank you for using PTK. Please press enter to exit.")

enum()
```

so my first issue, I believe is in my str.replace function, I am attempting to and an int to a str  and due to this it seems to be unable to create, ping, and print the correct ip. I'm unsure if converting the entire string to a floating int would work, however its a thought I'm toying with. as previously stated I am very basic with python and am working on learning so please forgive me if this  a stupid question with a simple fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't actually do anything. You need to assign the result to something.

```
ip.replace("x", ipend)
```

ipend is a string, incrementing a string won't work. Make it a int and convert it to a str in the replace function.

```
 ipend += 1
```

And it's usually better to use a for loop if you can, so you're safe from messing up and creating a infinite loop.

```
for ipend in range(1,256): #Range won't actually give you the last number here.
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: so as an example of the first part i should add something like  ip2=ip.replace

Comment: awesome thanks for the clean clear answer!  that's exactly why I love this site!

Comment: You're welcome, did you see the part about for loops?

Comment: I'd suggest to add a comment on `str.format` method usage instead of replace.

Comment: Using str.replace seems reasonable. Asking the user of this program to input the ip with an x where it should do replacing seems intuitive. Where would you use str.format here?

Comment: yes M4rtini I definitely saw the part about loops, thanks again

Comment: also I definitely have a small intro section asking the user to add the x, just left it out in the interest of saving space